# Different client IP address trying to connect to our db server during the deployment. how can we read them during the deployment

Tags: azure-powershell

Different client IP address trying to connect to our db server during the deployment. '20.236.53.215', 20.3.119.213, 20.29.245.120 are the client IP address trying to connect db server. what are these IP addresses and how can we read them during the deployment

how to read those IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are deploying from an Azure resource?

One way would be to whitelist these IP's programatically either through a declarative IaC language such as Terraform or Bicep, or a CLI (Powershell or Az CLI).

Since the IP used for deployment may vary, you may have to whitelist all available IP's used by the Azure data center in question. You can find a list of available IP's at
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519